# Call a functions with the same name from different file

Tags: python

Is it possible to have have a folder with python scripts, all of them contain the same method name. And have a master python script that runs each script function. Note that they functions to be run have the same name but are in different script.

This is to create a a framework that runs every task. Each task is going to have the same method name. And the master python is going to grab each task and run it.

File layout:

```
master.py
tasks/
    task1.py
    task2.py
```

task1.py:

```
def task:
    print("hello")
```

task2.py:

```
def task:
    print("world")
```

Note : I do not know how many tasks I can have

Comment: In my opinion, this is not a good way to solve whatever problem you're having - shell scripting might be more suitable for running all tasks within a directory.

Answer (score 4):

```
import task1
import task2

task1.task()
task2.task()
```

Or...

```
import task1 as task1_new_name
import task2 as task2_new_name

task1_new_name.task()
task2_new_name.task()
```

Or...

```
from task1 import task as task1 # or some other name
from task2 import task as task2 # or some other name

task1()
task2()
```

Or... (please NEVER do this)

```
exec("class task1:" + ("\n\t".join(open("task1.py").read().split("\n")))
exec("class task2:" + ("\n\t".join(open("task2.py").read().split("\n")))

task1.task()
task2.task()
```

EDIT:

You can use the `exec` function to do this dynamically.

```
for filename in filenames:
    exec("import " + filename)
    exec(filename + ".task()")
```

Comment: Is there a way to that dynamic? Cause I don't know how many task I can have

Comment: @user3630844: That's a different question...and I suggest you search for existing answers here on SO before asking it because I'm fairly sure it's been answer (so would get marked a duplicate). Doing it with `exec()` would **not** be considered a good approach...I would suggest using `getattr()` with the name given to the imported module.

Answer (score 4):

Create a new file in the `tasks` directory named `__init__.py`, and type the following:

```
__all__ = ['task1', 'task2']
```

You can dynamically generate a list of all the module names if necessary, but the variable has to be named `__all__`.

Then, in `master.py`

```
from tasks import *

task1.task()
task2.task()
```

This is the preferred way of packaging multiple modules in a directory within a Python project.

Comment: Still not an entire solution. Sure, he can generate `__all__`, but if he's going to be using fixed function calls why would he need to?

Comment: @J.Doe It's possible to write a function in `__init__.py` that exposes the `task()` functions of each module to the importing module.

Comment: Like a list of all the functions... hmm... that might be a good thing to give him an example of. Do you wanna edit yours, or should I edit mine?

Answer (score -1):

When you are importing into `master.py`, just import the module, and then call the function from that.

master.py

```
import task1 
import task2

task1.task()
task2.task()
```

task1.py

```
def task(): 
    print("hello")
```

task2.py:

```
def task(): 
    print("world")
```

Comment: Is there a way to do that dynamic? Cause I do not know how many tasks I can have